# How do I get links in a popup.js to open in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

This is a chrome extension that prints a list of links.
My code looks like this

```
function main(linkArray) {
for (var i = 0; i < linkArray.length; i++) {
document.write(linkArray[i].link(linkArray[i]) + "\n");
}
}
main(["example.com", "example2.com", "example3.com"]);
```

When the links are printed, if I click on them, nothing happens, but if I scroll-click (to open a new tab) they work fine. How do I make it so that if I left-click them, they open in a new tab?

Comment: Reading the code I get a bit confused. Isn't <link> only allowed in the <head> element? I would think <a href="blahblah" target="_blank"></a> is more typical html for showing a navigation link to users in a new tab. I don't build Chrome extensions.

Comment: @joshp sorry, I fixed the code, that's not what it actually looks like. You are correct as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `target` attribute to denote where the links open (with a regular click), for example:

```
<a href="example.com" target="_blank">link</a>
```

will open example.com in a new tab/window.

Since your code definitely doesn't provide links, I can't write you how to implement it exactly, but you should set [`target="_blank"`](https://css-tricks.com/use-target_blank/) on your anchors.